# Insert occurrence of something from one table into another

Tags: sql

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

There are 2 tables from the above example there one table is university name and block name, in table 1 there are university name and the teams they have in respective sports, in table 2 there are universities and sports according to block name and i want to add the number of occurrences of that sport in the table 1

This is just an example table, the main tables are really large but the principle is same

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server, you can do this:

```
update t1
set 
      Rugby = RugbyCount
    , Basketball = BasketballCount
    , Baseball = BaseballCount
from table1 t1
join ( select UNI 
             , count(case when sport ='Rugby' then 1 end) RugbyCount
             , count(case when sport ='Basketball' then 1 end) BasketballCount
             , count(case when sport ='Baseball' then 1 end) BaseballCount
       from table2
       group by  UNI 
     ) t2
join on t1.uni = t2.uni
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me on MySQL

```
update db.tbl t1 
join (select UNI, 
       (select count(SPORT) where SPORT= 'Rugby') CRugby,
       (select count(SPORT) where SPORT= 'Basketball') CBasketball,
       (select count(SPORT) where SPORT= 'Baseball') CBaseball,
  

from db.tb2
group by sport, UNI) t2 on t1.UNI = t2.UNI

set Rugby= CRugby,
    Basketball=  CBasketball,
    Baseball= CBaseball;
```